# I want to remove Json object from Json Array in Mysql 8. Column data type is Json

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I'm using Mysql 8.
I want to remove the specific object from JSON Array which has value like field_1568988989723 in Mysql JSON column

Here is my JSON

```
[{"section": {"name": "Basic Info", "order": 0, "fields": [{"name": "field_1568988989723", "order": 0}, {"name": "field_1568989125942", "order": 1}]}}]
```

I've used this way

```
UPDATE apps_object
    SET detail_view = JSON_REMOVE( 
        detail_view, REPLACE( 
            JSON_SEARCH( detail_view, 'all', 'field_1568992047479', null, '$**.fields' )
            , '"'
            , ''
        ) 
      ) where id = 34;
```

But it just removes

> "value":"field_1568988989723"

but not he whole object.
Is there any way to remove object in MySql not in Programing code?

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=325373d776f32a239a84b30b1f6812ea).

Comment: Thank you @wchiquito. It worked.
And now my query is

`UPDATE apps_object
SET detail_view =
  IFNULL(
    JSON_REMOVE(
      detail_view,
      JSON_UNQUOTE(
        REPLACE(
          JSON_SEARCH(detail_view, 'all', 'field_1568988989723', NULL, '$**.fields'),
          '.name',
          ''
        )
      )
    ),
    detail_view
  ) where id = 34;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm thankful to @wchiquito for solving my problem

```
[{"section": {"name": "Basic Info", "order": 0, "fields": [{"name": "field_1568988989723", "order": 0}, {"name": "field_1568989125942", "order": 1}]}}]
```

This is the query which solved my problem

```
UPDATE apps_object SET detail_view = IFNULL( JSON_REMOVE( detail_view, JSON_UNQUOTE( REPLACE( JSON_SEARCH(detail_view, 'all', 'field_1568988989723', NULL, '$**.fields'), '.name', '' ) ) ), detail_view ) where id = 34;
```

With the help of [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=325373d776f32a239a84b30b1f6812ea)